# Values are plotted out of order with a datetime axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

This is the code for showing the `'Close'` prices for Amazon, and visualizing the data using `matplotlib.pyplot` in Python.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('amzn_close.csv')
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date'].values))

plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.plot(df['Close'], label='Close')
plt.title('Close Price')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price USD')
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, it came out like this, with squiggly lines:

[image]

Can someone help me to present and visualize the data correctly?

### `amzn_close.csv`

```py
Date,Close
2021-03-05,3000.46
2021-04-01,3161.0
2021-03-17,3135.73
2021-02-23,3194.5
2021-03-10,3057.64
2021-03-16,3091.86
2021-03-18,3027.99
2021-02-25,3057.16
2021-04-15,3379.09
2021-03-22,3110.87
2021-04-14,3333.0
2021-03-25,3046.26
2021-03-24,3087.07
2021-02-26,3092.93
2021-04-20,3334.69
2021-04-19,3372.01
2021-04-16,3399.44
2021-04-08,3299.3
2021-03-08,2951.95
2021-03-30,3055.29
2021-03-02,3094.53
2021-03-09,3062.85
2021-02-24,3159.53
2021-02-22,3180.74
2021-04-22,3309.04
2021-03-01,3146.14
2021-03-15,3081.68
2021-03-26,3052.03
2021-04-05,3226.73
2021-03-31,3094.08
2021-03-03,3005.0
2021-04-23,3340.88
2021-04-26,3409.0
2021-03-19,3074.96
2021-03-23,3137.5
2021-04-21,3362.02
2021-03-29,3075.73
2021-04-12,3379.39
2021-04-07,3279.39
2021-04-13,3400.0
2021-04-27,3417.43
2021-04-06,3223.82
2021-03-12,3089.49
2021-03-11,3113.59
2021-03-04,2977.57
2021-04-09,3372.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Two things to always verify are:

  1. The `'Date'` should be set as a `datetime64[ns]` or `DatetimeIndex` `dtype`.

     - `pd.to_datetime()`
     - `pd.DatetimeIndex()`
     - Parse dates when importing data
  2. The value column, `'Close'`, should be a numeric `dtype`

  - Check the `dtypes` with `df.info()`

### Use `matplotlib` directly

- In this case, only the `index` needs to be sorted, because the `y-axis` is already numeric and the `x-axis` is already a `datetime dtype`.
- The `csv` can also be read in with:

  - `df = pd.read_csv('amzn_close.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'])`

```py
# load and format the data
df = pd.read_csv('amzn_close.csv')
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date'].values))

# sort the index
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

# plot
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 7))
plt.plot(df['Close'], label='Close')
plt.title('Close Price')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price USD')
plt.show()
```

### Use [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

- Doesn't require sorting the `index`

```py
# load the data
df = pd.read_csv('amzn_close.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'])

# plot the data
df.plot(figsize=(16, 7), title='Close Price', ylabel='Price USD', rot=0, legend=False)
```

### Use [`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html)

- Doesn't require sorting the `index`

```py
# load the data
df = pd.read_csv('amzn_close.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'])

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 7))
sns.lineplot(data=df, ax=ax, legend=False)
ax.set(title='Close Price', xlabel='Date', ylabel='Price USD')
```

### Output for all implementations

[image]

### Notes

- Package versions:

  - `pandas v1.2.4`
  - `seaborn v0.11.1`
  - `matplotlib v3.3.4`